# Don't know if I'm copying these integers the wrong way, but I'm getting some weird errors

Tags: c, shell

I'm getting the following errors, hopefully someone can explain these errors for me as I'm not very good in C at the moment.

```
case ' ':     
This is the error here. shellNew.c:57: error: a label can only be part of a statement and                 a declaration is not a statement

int rCheck = 0;
shellNew.c:58: error: expected expression before â

int foundPos = 0;
while(rCheck < 10)
{
  if(inputBuffer[2] == historyBuffer[rCheck][0])
  {
shellNew.c:63: error: â undeclared (first use in this function)
shellNew.c:63: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
shellNew.c:63: error: for each function it appears in.)

  foundPos = rCheck;
  }
rCheck++;
}
if(rCheck == 0)
{
  printf("There was no command matching your criteria\n");
}
else
{
  strcpy(inputBuffer, historyBuffer[rCheck]);
}
break;
```

Comment: The first error might be reported because your code starts with *case ' ':* which isn't legal outside of a switch statement. The â characters are there because gcc likes to use some funky backquote character that xterm doesn't like. Use another terminal program (or a new version of xterm, maybe?) to see the full error message. If you're not using xterm, then whatever you're using doesn't like those characters, either.

Comment: I suspect the accented characters are due to GCC producing interesting characters in the output and the copy/paste not handling them well.  I get that problem sometimes.

Comment: Can you please post the complete code as-is?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that there was a `switch` in the previous 56 lines of code, then the compiler is complaining that you can't do:

```
switch (variable)
{
case ' ':
    int var = 23;
```

because the declaration doesn't count as a statement and labels must be attached to statements.  Converted into a minuscule function, this code gave me the error you report with GCC 4.7.1 on Mac OS X 10.7.5.  The subsequent errors are probably because your variable `rCheck` was not declared because of the misplaced label, leading to problems where you try to use it.

You can't skip over variable declarations, so you'll need to use a statement block inside the `switch` statement block:

```
switch (variable)
{
case ' ':
    {
    int var = 23;
    ...
    }
    break;
}
```

This code compiled cleanly.  It's a moot point whether it's better to put the `break` inside the statement block or outside; they're equivalent.